# VBA Macro - Copy Partial Row from Below Based on Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, copy, partial

I'm really new to VBA and trying to figure out how to create a loop so that, when the value in column A is “1”, the values from columns E to N in the row immediately below are copied to the row above (without inserting a new row, just pasting over the existing values). I’ve been through the course book and dozens of Excel forums and can’t see a way of doing this? Is it possible?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Try to search in Column A and then replace the value of E and N using OFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Sub test()
   Dim n as Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   n = 100
   For i = 1 To n
       If CInt(Range("a" & i)) = 1 Then
           Range("e" & i + 1 & ":n" & i + 1).Copy
           Range("e" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       End If
   Next i

   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm getting 'variable not defined' but will see if I can fix. Just so I understand this, if I wanted to alter this to action on a text value instead, could I change the first part to Dim n as String and alter the values accordingly?

Comment: To fix _variable not defined_ you need to add `Dim i As Integer` (I've updated my answer). If you want to alter this to action on a text, you need to change line `If CInt(Range("a" & i)) = 1 Then` to `If CStr(Range("a" & i)) = "someText" Then`